# How can i put the token function in one file and import where i need

Tags: angular7

How do i put he jwt header code in one file and import it where ever i need to instead to writing it in every function i need

```
getStaffCode(){
    var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if(token == undefined){
      alert ("Token error");
   }
   else{
    var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const requestOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'bearer ' + token}),
    }
    return this.http.get(environment.url + 'api/Staffs',requestOptions);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically for this case, you may want to use an http interceptor to add the token to each request, have a look a [this article](https://scotch.io/@vigneshsithirai/angular-6-7-http-client-interceptor-with-error-handling).

You can implement a response interceptor aswell and control from 1 point every request.

Answer (score 0):

in order to that, you can simply use service. it means according to the concept meaning of service, we use services to make our activity easy and comfortable. we can conduct this meaning in Angular as well. we use service to make our code cleaner and it is really useful to prevent violating the concept of separation of concern. so first make a service in angular, like this :

```
   export class GetToken{

        getToken(){
             let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
             return token; 
        }    

  }
```

and wherever you need token just simply use the service. for example in the ts file we have:

```
    constructor(private token : GetToken){}


   ngOnInit(){
     let token = this.token.getToken();


  }
```

i hope it is useful for you.